# Google map multiple pointer for same latitude and longitude

Tags: google-maps-markers

I am working with the google map multiple pointer using latitude and longitude.i calculated my latitude and longitude using the address(street,city,state), in that some users having a same address so we got a same latitude and longitude

```
Example:
User1 latitude:38.65367, longitude:-90.3547059
User2 latitude:38.65367, longitude:-90.3547059.
```

I want to load the map with multiple pointer, since the latitude and longitude is same

How can i achive my expected result, your idea and suggestion will help me more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically you want to add 2 identical markers in the same identical location, and the problem is that you are not able to see that there are 2 markers there.

So there is no really quick fix to that ,  what you can do is add a hover event to the marker letting the user know that there are 2 items at this address, or when adding a new marker you can check if the lat and long already exist in your array of markers and if they do then add a different type of marker.  The new one can have an image of the number "2" in the marker , you could use a different color, etc.

You kind of have to take a step back here and decide what you want from a user-experience point of view , then decide how to tackle that in code

Comment: yes, you are right, but If the user zoom the map means he can able to view the same address multiple pointer, i got the answer 2 months back, as per that i added the csgeoxml.js file and it was worked fine, but now its not working as per my expectation. do you have any other idea to solve this issue

Comment: I personally think it's a bad user experience , either just leave it look as one maker , or use some type of creative solution to let the user know that  there are 2 markers there such as a different marker.  making the user zoom all the way in to find out there are 2 markers isn't right

Comment: scott:okay i will try to find some creative way to find the answer or follow as per your mention way.